# Can we create a zero filled section in an elf file with gnu ld?

Tags: gnu, microcontroller, ld, bare-metal

Is there a way of creating an explicitly zeroed out bss section in an elf file with gnu ld? I have a baremetal environment where I have the option of initializing the memories before the system starts and this option would be much quicker than zeroing out the bss once the system starts.

Comment: I don't understand -- a .bss section is solely the space for zero-initialized data

Comment: If I have a bss that is 64 bytes long, I want a bss section in the elf that has a loadable section with 64 zero bytes in it.

Answer (score 0):

In the linker script add *(.bss) to the data section instead of the .bss section.